# Add dead region touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, macbook, mac, multi-touch

Is there a way to set a region of my touch pad as "dead" ignoring touch input?

The reason for this is that I have a MacBook pro late 2011 and there the "button" is on the touch page itself.

Anyone got any ideas? :D

Answer (score 11):

You could try using a combination of something like the following to disable strips on the sides, top and bottom of the touchpad.

```
synclient AreaLeftEdge=w AreaRightEdge=x AreaTopEdge=y AreaBottomEdge=z
```

To figure out what w,x,y and z would be, you'll need to know the range, or boundaries of the touchpad, which might show in the Xorg log, as in my case. I don't have a Macbook, but an example will do to illustrate the method.

To find out the touchpad boundaries, run `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i range`.
Here is the output I get:

```
(II) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 8 - 1144
(II) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 8 - 760
```

**UPDATE:**

If for some reason, the above command no longer works because Xorg.0.log has changed location, you would also be able to get edge coordinates from synclient directly.

```
synclient
```

gives:

```
LeftEdge                = 8
RightEdge               = 1144
TopEdge                 = 8
BottomEdge              = 760
```

**UPDATE-END**

Now, to disable strips on both sides and at the bottom, I've added the following to autostart applications:

```
synclient AreaLeftEdge=50 AreaRightEdge=1100 AreaBottomEdge=670
```

It took some trial and error to adjust the widths to comfortable levels, so you might what to experiment in a terminal window first, before adding it to autostart. The changes are applied instantly.

Comment: Thanks. My rightpalm was the bain of my typing existence. Setting AreaRightEdge work brilliantly. I would add one thing to your answer, you're able to get the exact coordinates of the edge from synclient itself.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem:when part of my palm rests of the left edge (accidentally) it blocks scrolling with the right hand. This blockage seems to keep happening even when I define a dead left reigon